# Sending AS3 variables to and email using PHP

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a flash content on my website that contains an input box and a submit button. The user should put an answer of a question in the input box and when he clicks on submit, the answer should be sent to an email address. The problem is, when a user enters an answer, I receive an email that contains :

```
array (
)
```

. Here are my codes:

**AS3 Code:**

```
var myData:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
myData.answer = answer.text;
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("example.php");
myRequest.data = myData;
myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
```

**The button's code:**

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sen) ;
function sen(Event:MouseEvent):void
{
navigateToURL( new URLRequest("example.php"), "_self");
}
```

**The PHP code:**

```
<?php
$text = var_export($_POST, true);
$to = "webhosting4@outlook.com";
$subject="Message from php";
mail($to,$subject,$text,"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
?>
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sen) ;

function sen(Event:MouseEvent):void
{
   var myData:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
   myData.answer = answer.text;

   var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("example.php");
   myRequest.data = myData;
   myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

   var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
   loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
   loader.load( myRequest );
};
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I've been searching for a solution for a long time.